# Not finding a file uploaded to server in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

When I put an audio file in the server directory in ASP.NET and I tried to open it from the media player by its url, I get an error

> We could not open <file_name> please wait a bit, then try again

I tried to send a `GET` request using Postman and I get a status code: 404 - resource not found.

I am using .NET 7.0 I used the `app.UseStaticFiles()` method and I put the file in the project directory the url I was using was http://appUrl/fileName(with extension)

How can I store a file on the server and access it with its URL?

Comment: Use the `wwwroot` directory within your project, not the same directory that the `.csproj` is located in.

Comment: @Dai this acually worked when I created the wwwroot folder and put the files in it, I can access it from the media player or by sending a request from postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that your project has a wwwroot directory, and the file is placed inside it. ASP.NET serves static files from the wwwroot directory by default. If you don't have one please create a wwwroot folder and place your files there.

```
|-- YourProject
   |-- wwwroot
      |-- yourfile.mp3
   |-- ...
```